# jq: Format a JSON file with the output replacing the input file

Tags: json, optimization, cmd, file-io, jq

I want to use `jq` to format a JSON file in Windows.  So far, I haven't been able to find a way to perform this task using a single `jq` command.

Thus, I wrote this batch file:

```
rem create formatted JSON output file
jq-win64.exe . "%1" >"temp.tmp"

rem replace the unformatted JSON input file with the formatted JSON output file
del "%1"
ren "temp.tmp" "%1"
```

Is there a way to instruct `jq` to do this without performing these gymnastics?

Comment: `jq` cannot do in-place editing, what you can do is replace `del&ren` with `move "temp.tmp" "%1"`

Comment: @Philippe Thanks Phillippe.  And there's no way to specify the same file as input and output?  The JSON files I'm processing are all under 2MB, so memory isn't an issue.  I've read that `jq` supports "slurping" input, but I'm still unclear if that could help.  If none of what I just wrote leads to a change in your comment, feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I'll upvote & accept it after I give the rest of our community a chance to propose answers.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket The problem is that `>` will delete the content of the file before `jq` could read it. A lot of commands that support in-place edition do so by creating a temporary file with the output and then overwrite the content of the original file.

Comment: `"slurping"` concerns only the processing (reading) of the file, so won't help here.

Comment: @Fravadona Thank you for the details.

Comment: @Philippe Thank you for explaining "slurping" a little more.  One of these days, I hope to understand what the jq author truly means by that term.

Answer (score 2):

You want the following:

```
jq . "%1" >"%1".tmp
if not errorlevel 1 move /y "%1".tmp "%1" >nul
```

`jq` has no option to do this for you.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your answer.  I've upvoted it for now, and I'll also accept it if no one writes a better answer within a week or so.  If I forget to come back to this question, feel free to ping me.

Comment: It might be a good idea to use the TEMP directory which is intended for TEMP files. `>"%TEMP%\%~1.tmp"`

Comment: @lit, That doesn't make sense here. Keep in mind this is NOT a temp file. Just a temporary name for the new file. Putting it on what might be a different volume causes problems.